# Django: Pass parameter to Form in Admin

Tags: python, django

I have two models called `Event` and `Registration`. Each `Registration` has as ForeignKey an `Event` object.

Now, in my web application I provide a `RegistrationForm` so that people can register for an event.

Example: A user can register at `/event/<pk>/register/`. From the URL I get the event the user would like to register for and pass the public key of the event to the `RegistrationForm`.

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        exclude = ['event']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.event = kwargs.pop('pk')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the form I, of course, do not display the event field (so that's why it's excluded). Because when the user is at e.g. `/event/5/register/` is clear that he would like to register for event `5`.

In the view I create the Form using `form = RegistrationForm(pk=pk)`.

In case you know a better solution how to solve this, please come up with it. :)

**Now the problem:**

In my `RegistrationForm` I have also some validation logic and when I create/edit a new `Registration` object in the Admin, I'd also like to have those validations.

```
class RegistrationInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Registration
    extra = 0
    form = RegistrationForm

@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EventForm

    inlines = [RegistrationInline]
```

Thing is, however, that my `RegistrationForm` does need the public key of the event and I do not know how to solve that problem. I looked at the Django documentation, but I am overwhelmed about the many methods and functionality as a beginner.

What is a good solution?

Here my validations in the RegistrationForm:

```
def clean_number_of_tickets(self):
    number_of_tickets = self.cleaned_data.get('number_of_tickets')
    # Event object
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=self.event)

    if self.instance.number_of_tickets:
        available = self.instance.number_of_tickets + event.get_number_of_available_tickets()
    else:
        available = event.get_number_of_available_tickets()
    if number_of_tickets > available:
        raise ValidationError()

    return number_of_tickets
```

Comment: Forgot the main thing — to show us the validations you have.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov: I've added the validations.

Comment: Ummm. Let me think, I don't quite get the logic, that you're trying to achieve. Can you show the Registration model too please.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov:
With the "Registration" the users can register for an Event with a number of tickets. The RegisterForm is for creating and updating registrations. In my validation I want to make sure that someone does not register more tickets than available.